# Print an integer array as hexadecimal numbers

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array created by using

```
array1 = np.array([[25,  160,   154, 233],
                   [61, 244,  198,  248],
                   [227, 226, 141, 72 ],
                   [190, 43,  42, 8]],np.int) ;
```

which displays as

```
[[25,  160, 154, 233]
 [61,  244, 198, 248]
 [227, 226, 141,  72]
 [190,  43,  42 ,  8]]
```

How do I display this array as hexadecimal numbers like this:

```
[[0x04,  0xe0,  0x48, 0x28]
 [0x66,  0xcb,  0xf8, 0x06]
 [0x81,  0x19,  0xd3, 0x26]
 [0xe5,  0x9a,  0x7a, 0x4c]]
```

Note: numbers in hex may not be real conversions of numbers in int. I have filled hex array just to give example of what I need.

Comment: What version of numpy are you using (`np.version.version`)?

Answer (score 39):

You can set the print options for numpy to do this.

```
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(formatter={'int':hex})
np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
```

gives

```
array([0x1L, 0x2L, 0x3L, 0x4L, 0x5L])
```

The L at the end is just because I am on a 64-bit platform and it is sending longs to the formatter. To fix this you can use

```
np.set_printoptions(formatter={'int':lambda x:hex(int(x))})
```

Comment: FYI for the OP.  The `formatter` parameter for `set_printoptions` appears in the 2.0 docs, but not in 1.6.  So I imagine it's a new feature.  If you have an older version, you could roll your own formatting function and supply it to numpy with `numpy.set_string_function`.  The function you supply would need to format *the whole array* rather than a single item like in Justin's answer.

Comment: For those like myself who doesn't want print options to be changed in a global scope there is a [numpy.printoptions](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.printoptions.html) helper method now, that you can use like: `with np.printoptions(formatter={'int':hex}):`

Answer (score 22):

Python has a built-in hex function for converting integers to their hex representation (a string). You can use numpy.vectorize to apply it over the elements of the multidimensional array.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
>>> vhex = np.vectorize(hex)
>>> vhex(A)
array([['0x1', '0x2'],
       ['0x3', '0x4']], 
      dtype='<U8')
```

There might be a built-in method of doing this with numpy which would be a better choice if speed is an issue.

Comment: -0, due to the existence of `numpy.set_printoptions`.

Comment: The vectorize is handy when only an occasional hex string is needed. Otherwise would need to original=get_printoptions(), set_printoptions(hex), print hex, set_printoptions(original)

Comment: Amazing solution, very pythonic.

Answer (score 6):

If what you're looking for it's just for display you can do something like this:

```
>>> a = [6, 234, 8, 9, 10, 1234, 555, 98]
>>> print '\n'.join([hex(i) for i in a])
0x6
0xea
0x8
0x9
0xa
0x4d2
0x22b
0x62
```

Answer (score 5):

Just throwing in my two cents you could do this pretty simply using list comprehension if it's always a 2d array like that

```
a = [[1,2],[3,4]]
print [map(hex, l) for l in a]
```

which gives you `[['0x1', '0x2'], ['0x3', '0x4']]`

Answer (score 3):

This one-liner should do the job:

```
print '[' + '],\n['.join(','.join(hex(n) for n in ar) for ar in array1) + ']'
```

Comment: -0, due to the existence of `numpy.set_printoptions`.

Comment: Yes, that's definitely a better solution. Question asker, please see Justin Peel's answer, and don't use mine.

Comment: Numpy is absolutely a better solution! If you have access to numpy.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to get the behavior you want with [`numpy.set_printoptions`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html#numpy-set-printoptions), using the `formatter` keyword arg. It takes a dictionary with a type specification (i.e. `'int'`) as key and a callable object returning the string to print. I'd insert code but my old version of `numpy` doesn't have the functionality yet. (ugh.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using vectorized [np.base_repr](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.base_repr.html) since I needed my result rjusted with padded 0's

```py
import numpy as np

width = 4
base = 16
array1 = np.array([[25,  160,   154, 233],
                   [61, 244,  198,  248],
                   [227, 226, 141, 72 ],
                   [190, 43,  42, 8]],np.int)


base_v = np.vectorize(np.base_repr)
padded = np.char.rjust(base_v(array1, base), width, '0')
result = np.char.add('0x', padded)
```

Output:

```
[['0x0019' '0x00A0' '0x009A' '0x00E9']
 ['0x003D' '0x00F4' '0x00C6' '0x00F8']
 ['0x00E3' '0x00E2' '0x008D' '0x0048']
 ['0x00BE' '0x002B' '0x002A' '0x0008']]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
array1_hex = np.array([[hex(int(x)) for x in y] for y in array1])
print array1_hex
# => array([['0x19', '0xa0', '0x9a', '0xe9'],
#           ['0x3d', '0xf4', '0xc6', '0xf8'],
#           ['0xe3', '0xe2', '0x8d', '0x48'],
#           ['0xbe', '0x2b', '0x2a', '0x8']], 
#          dtype='|S4')
```

Comment: This answer fails with error: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable