# numpy - printing *only one* column from matrix as hex

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, hex

i can't find an easy way in numpy to display a matrix with one column shown as hex, the rest as decimal.
found answer regarding [how to print *everything* as hex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9448099/866439), but i want just one column.

here's what i have: data looks like this:

```
array([[120258560,         3],
       [167772160,       339],
       [118948100,         1],
       [ 50331904,         1]])
```

the first column is an error code, the second is the number of times it occurs. error code is easy to read in hex, number of times it occurs is easy to read in decimal.
i'd like to be able to do this:

```
array([['0X72B0000',         3],
       ['0xa000000',       339],
       ['0X7170104',         1],
       ['0X3000100',         1]])
```

tips? (:

---

my current solution is a wrapper around this, which works but is ugly:

```
hex_col = hex_col = np.array(([hex(x)[:-1] for x in data[:,0]]))
err_in_hex = np.transpose([hex_col, data[:,1]])
```

`err_in_hex` looks like:

```
array([['0x72b0000', '3'],
       ['0xa000000', '339'],
       ['0x7170104', '1'],
       ['0x3000100', '1']],
      dtype='|S9')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For display purposes just iterate on the rows, and format each row as needed:

```
In [303]: for row in data:
     ...:     print hex(row[0])[:-1], row[1]
     ...:     
0x72b0000 3
0xa000000 339
0x7170104 1
0x3000100 1
```

or with more formatting:

```
In [307]: print '\n'.join(['%10s %10d'%(hex(row[0])[:-1], row[1]) for row in data])
 0x72b0000          3
 0xa000000        339
 0x7170104          1
 0x3000100          1
```

Regular array formatting does something like `tolist()`, and then applies the format controls to that.  So you don't lose anything by doing your own row by row formatting.

If you want to collect the hex string and the numeric (not string) data into one array, you need a compound dtype, a structured array.  You could make it as:

```
In [317]: hex_col = [hex(x)[:-1] for x in data[:,0]]
In [318]: data1=np.zeros(data.shape[0],dtype='S10,int')
In [319]: data1['f0']=hex_col
In [320]: data1['f1']=data[:,1]

In [321]: data1
Out[321]: 
array([('0x72b0000', 3), ('0xa000000', 339), ('0x7170104', 1),
       ('0x3000100', 1)], 
      dtype=[('f0', 'S10'), ('f1', '<i4')])
```