# ERROR 'Series' object cannot be interpreted as an integer, I don't know what I do

Tags: python

My code:

```
import pandas as pd

datos=pd.read_csv('/Users/rafaelsuarez/Documents/Data/UCELL.csv', sep=',' , encoding='latin-1')
df=pd.DataFrame(datos)
df['RNC']=df['RNC'].map('RNC_{}'.format)

h=hex(df['LAC'])
```

The data is:

```
MCC,MNC,LAC,CELLID,CELLNAME,RNC,NODEBNAME,AZIMUTH_ANTENNA,LON,LAT
730,09,119,20011,AIS_3G_001_1_B1,PTM01,AIS_3G_001,20,-72.6906,-45.4044
730,09,119,20014,AIS_3G_001_1_B2,PTM01,AIS_3G_001,20,-72.6906,-45.4044
```

I need to convert 'LAC' in hexa.

Comment: You certainly don't want to change the data in the column.  That would turn it into a string.  Remember, the stored data is neither decimal nor hex.  It's all binary.  Hex is just how we humans display things.  There is no easy way to display one column in hex, without doing the formatting yourself, row by row.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36599793/numpy-printing-only-one-column-from-matrix-as-hex

Answer (score 1):

The error arises as the function `hex()` operates on integers, whereas you are applying it to a pandas Series object.

Compare the behaviour of `math.sin(df['LAC'])` which throws an error similar to yours as `math.sin()` operates on single numbers (in this case floating point numbers), and `np.sin(df['LAC'])`, which operates on a numpy array (or similar object like a pandas Series).

One way to achieve what you want is to apply `hex()` to each element of the Series using a list comprehension:

```
h = [hex(x) for x in df['LAC']]
```