# Hex to a String Python

Tags: python, string, numpy, hex

I would like to convert

the hex value

```
a = 0x32
```

to a string `d = 32`

Bascially I have a  numpy array

```
msg = np.array[2, 50]
```

I need to convert both values to hex --- `[0x02 , 0x32]`
then print the hex values as strings on GUI as 2, 32

Comment: Thank you for editing @kasramvd

Comment: Here is a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9448029/print-an-integer-array-as-hexadecimal-numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hex()` will give you hex string.  Then discard first 2 characters

```
>>> hex(a)
'0x32'
>>> hex(a)[2:]
'32'
>>>
```

Looking at the link to duplicate, it seems numpy is giving you the L at the end since you are running 64bit linux.  so do this:

```
hex(a)[2:-1]
```

Comment: I have 0x32L not 0x32, Could you also tell me why I have 0x32L ?

Comment: do you always have L at the end? what python version?

Comment: PYthon 2.7 Version

Comment: Try this :
msg = np.array([2 ,50])
d = hex(msg[1])
print d