# Loading a .mat file containing hexadecimal numbers

Tags: python

I have a .mat file, which contains two variables, x and y. x is a hexadecimal number matrix, the type of whose elements is string and y is an int vector. I import scipy.io as sio and use sio.loadmat('data.mat') to load the .mat file. However, x becomes a zero matrix and the type of its elements is numpy.float64. Is there any method that I can correctly load the hexadecimal number variable saved in a .mat file?

Comment: You might mix hexdecimal and int. Hexdeciamal is a format to read data, int is a type of data.

Comment: You can print the data as hex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9448029/print-an-integer-array-as-hexadecimal-numbers